# Выборка из двух баз за один запрос

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Добрый день. Хотел узнать, возможно ли выбрать информацию из разных баз данных за один запрос?

Comment: А можно ли сделать так в postgresql?
У меня не получилось.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в запросе таблица указывается с именем базы данных `database1.table1`, то таблица выбирается из `database1`, если просто `table1`, то - из активной базы данных.

Общий принцип перекрестного запроса к двум базам в пределах одного MySQL-сервера:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM database1.table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN database2.table2 AS t2 ON t2.field1 = t1.field1
```

Алиасы `t1` и `t2` использовать не обязательно. Но они уменьшают размер запроса, и улучшают читабельность.

Comment: понял а как совершать поключение, к обоим базам или только подключив к одной я смогу иметь доступ и к другой?

Comment: Подключаетесь вы к СУБД, а затем выбираете активную БД ( что в данном случае не обязательно )

Comment: Опечатка в ответе: "... t2.field1 = t2.field1"

Answer (score 1):

Если у того пользователя, под именем которого вы работаете с сервером б.д. есть доступ к обоим базам данных, то способ, описанный выше, будет работать.

```
SELECT `first_db`.`some_table`.`col_name`, `second_db`.`some_other_table`.`col_name`
FROM `first_db`.`some_table`
INNER JOIN `second_db`.`some_other_table` ON (`first_db`.`some_table`.`some_id` = `second_db`.`some_other_table`.`id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Да можно ответы даны, но нада чтобы базы были на одном сервере

Comment: а пользователь тоже должен быть один?

Answer (score -1):

Можно!

```
SELECT `имя_первой_базы`.`поле`, `имя_второй_базы`.`поле` FROM `имя_первой_базы`, `имя_второй_базы`
```

Comment: Блин, поспешил)))) ща исправлюсь))

Comment: а этот способ не для таблиц разве?

Comment: для таблиц))) я поспешил просто)

Comment: да я понял просто мы одновременно написали коментарий