# Select запрос к 2 базам данных

Tags: sql, select

У меня есть 2 бд в каждой по 1 таблице.

localdb с таблицей Client и AccessDataBase с таблицей ORDERS

пытался сделать как [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/53344/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

Вышло вот это

```
SELECT        
td1.*,
td2.*
FROM Client td1
JOIN AccessDatabase.ORDERS td2 ON td1.email=td2.email
```

Имя первой базы данных я не вставил во FROM потому что на ней и формирую запрос. Собственно он говорит что не понимает что такое AccessDatabase.

П.С. Я только учусь могу какие то базовые вещи не понимать)

Запросы делаю в visualStudio через

[image: вот это вот].

Не знаю как это называется)

Comment: AccessDatabase он пинимает как таблицу, а не базу... не уверен, но вроде как так делать нельзя

Comment: *пытался сделать как вот тут* Напрасно. MS Access и MySQL - это две большие разницы.

Comment: *он говорит что не понимает что такое AccessDatabase* Правильно, ибо это другое подключение. А должно быть внутри текущего.

Comment: @Akina А как то сделать то можно?